# Ввод тестовых данных из .txt в vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Возможно ли реализовать в VS code ввод тестовых значений, как это организованно в PyCharm (из обычного txt файла, что бы не вводить каждый раз новые данные вручную и просто нажимать на запуск кода.

[image: сам тест]

[image: Тестовые денные в txt]

[image: Как реализовано в Пайчарм]

Comment: Через системный терминал запускаете: `python small.py < input.txt`

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую!

Answer (score 0):

Четыре раза вызывая `input()` вы читаете четыре строки из файла. Правильный вариант, например

```py
a, b, c, d = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

"Redirect input from" опция как раз то что надо и у вас правильно сконфигурировано.